# Problems With This jQuery Selector

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi all I have a (probably) simple problem but I just can't figure out why it's not working.

The code below should be fairly easy to follow:

```
<?php
require('../db.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>Website Checker</title> 

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#check').click(function(){

$('.http-status').html('<img src="images/spinner.gif"/>').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');

$('#site-list li.websites').each(function()
{
    //var newurl = $(this).find('span.url a').attr('href');
    var newurl = $(this).find('span.url').html();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "process.php",
        data:    ({"a":newurl}),
        cache:   false,
        success: function(message)
        {
            $(this).find('span.http-status').html(message);
        } //End AJAX return
    }); //End AJAX call
    }); //End li each
}); //End Check

$('#check').click();

});

</script>

<ul id="site-list" class="list"> 
<li class="title">
    <span class="id"></span>
    <span class="name">Title</span>
    <span class="url">URL</span>
    <span class="status">HTTP Status</span>
</li> 
<?php
// some PHP to fetch all the gig entries from the shows table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `check`";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
// a loop to place all the values in the appropriate table cells
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
//begin the loop...
$id=$row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];
$url=$row['url'];
?>
<li class="websites">
    <span class="id"><?php echo $id; ?></span>
    <span class="name"><?php echo $name; ?></span> 
    <span class="url"><?php echo $url; ?></span>
    <span class="status http-status"></span>
</li>

<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<br /> 
<a href="#" id="check" class="button">Check Now</a>
```

This basically pulls site data from a db and presents it to the user and what I am trying to do is when you click the button for the http code of each site to be checked and displayed (and also run upon the page first being loaded)

This seems to work fine - the correct data is sent and recieved but then after that the spinner is STILL there!

link: http://www.4playtheband.co.uk/check/

process.php (if it helps):

```
<?php
require('../db.php');

$url= NULL;
if(isset($_POST['a'])) {    $url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a']);   }

function Visit($url)
{
$agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$page=curl_exec($ch);

//echo curl_error($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) 
{
    echo '<span class="up">'.$httpcode.'<span class="icon"><img src="images/info.png" alt="website is up"/></span></span>'; exit;
}
else
{
    $httpcode=404;

    $date = date("l, j \of F Y \@ H:i");

    $to      = "someone@domain.com";
    $subject = "Urgent: $url is down";
    $message = "Hello,\n\nIt appears that on our latest check of $url on $date that the site was down.\n\nRegards,\nWeb Checker";
    $headers = 'From: noreply@webchecker.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: noreply@webchecker.co.uk' . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo '<span class="down">'.$httpcode.'<span class="icon"><img src="images/info.png" alt="website is down"/></span></span>'; exit;
}
}

if(!empty($url)){ Visit($url); exit; } 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to `.http-status` element within each `li` in the success callback. Since you are making `ajax` calls in a loop we need to store each `li` object into local variable and create a closure by calling a method which will set the status message. Try this

```
$('#check').click(function(){

$('.http-status').html('<img src="images/spinner.gif"/>').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');


$('#site-list li.websites').each(function()
{
    var $li = $(this);

    //var newurl = $(this).find('span.url a').attr('href');
    var newurl = $(this).find('span.url').html();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "process.php",
        data:    ({"a":newurl}),
        cache:   false,
        success: function(message)
        {
            setStatusMessage(message, $li);

        } //End AJAX return
    }); //End AJAX call
    }); //End li each
}); //End Check

   function setStatusMessage(message, li){
       li.find('.http-status').html(message);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
$(this).find('span.http-status').html(message);
```

According to the [jQuery `.ajax` documentation][1]:

> The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

To get around this problem, you can assign the value of `$( this )` to another variable, and access that variable in the body of the `success` callback:

```
$('#site-list li.websites').each(function()
{
    theElement = $( this );
    var newurl = $(this).find('span.url').html();
    $.ajax(
    {
        // ...
        success: function(message)
        {
            theElement.html(message);
        } //End AJAX return
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are only setting the 'span' of the .http-status to the message, so the spinner is still in .http-status

You need to clear .http-status::

```
success: function(message)
    {
        $('.http-status').html('');
        $(this).find('span.http-status').html(message);
    } //End AJAX return
```

Comment: thanks, the span is now emptied after the ajax call but the response message is still not appearing :/

Comment: The span should not be emptied, thats where you are putting your data it looks like...  before you fill your span, you need to empty the parent container $('.http-status'), that will removed the spinner